# Paypal C# API: CreateInvoiceRequest dueDate

Tags: c#, paypal, invoice

I'm having an issue when using Paypal's CreateInvoiceRequest so the question is:

What is the datetime format used by **CreateInvoiceRequest.dueDate** (or CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest)?

All the [documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_CreateInvoice) says is:

> xs:dateTime (Optional) Dateon which the invoice payment is due.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Using the format specifier "s" (ex: 2009-06-15T13:45:30) works for Paypal.

Comment: I tried some ("d", "f", "g") of the standard datetime formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) . I guess Paypal's documentation should be more detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely ISO 8601, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats . Use `XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now)` to see how it looks.

However, how do you consume PayPal's web-service? You may find Visual Studio's integrated web-service referencing tools useful, such as `[Your Project in Solution Explorer] -> References -> [Right Click] -> Add Service Reference`, in such a case the web-service wrappers will be generated automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks! The format was close. By trial and error, I ended up using the format specifier "s", which gives me: "2009-06-15T13:45:30" and Paypal is happy about it. I'm new to this API so I'll check your recommendation.